# Message is not post on FB

Tags: xcode, facebook

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

```
[controller setInitialText:kShareViaFacebookMessage];
[controller addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:kShareViaFacebookURL]];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

what is the issue in this code? why it is not displaying message on post?

Comment: The user have to type the message.

Comment: kShareViaFacebookMessage=@"here message string" ;    user  also write but automatically it should be display... it is working on iOS 10 +.      but it is not working 9.3

Comment: So who wrote the text you want to be automatically displayed? What does it say?

Comment: [controller setInitialText:@"Test Case"];     Although I used this code but invain.

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: yes, it will be displayed automatically.

Comment: Prefilling is not allowed by Facebook platform policy